# sitting the image to fit any given page format

Tags: java, printing

I'm having a problem sitting the image to the proper with and height the following code prints correctly in an A4 format but not for a pvc cr80 card (like identity card) the above is the code implemented:

```
try {
    String cn = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(cn); // Use the native L&F
} catch (Exception cnf) {
}

PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

printJob.setPrintable(new Printable() {
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        if (pageIndex > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }


        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;


        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(),pageFormat.getImageableY());

        g2d.drawImage(im, 0, 0,(int)pageFormat.getImageableWidth(),(int)pageFormat.getImageableHeight(), null);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
});
boolean ok = printJob.printDialog();
if (ok) {
    try {
        printJob.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't print");
    }
}
```

and this is the result:
http://s12.postimg.org/ij3pic2vh/Capture.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have to look more into PrinterJob Printable and PageFormat. Read the specifications.

The getImageableWidth() is returned as inches not pixels so that will affect your printing.

Comment: thank u for replying fast; What should I do then? how can I force this ? I'm really stuck with this for days now!